# Apply CSS to Specific Field Contents in List Display Form

Tags: list, css

I'm trying to target some .CSS styling to the contents of a specific field on the display form of a list, but I can't get the right syntax.  The style changes work fine in IE developer, but I can't translate that into working .css that Sharepoint recognizes in a CEWP.  The fieldname is "Task", internalfieldname is "Title".

[image: IE Developer]

```
.ms-formbody id=SPFieldText {font-weight, size, etc.} does not work.
```

Answer (score 1):

You Can use
`<style>
td.ms-formbody
{
/*your style*/
}
</style>`

If the styling generated in inline, you have to remove the inline styling and apply your style.In the above screenshot if the page is in your control, you have to remove the "style" or you have to incorporate your style there itself.

Since your are using web-part this should be in web part or the external css file that should be reffed in web-part

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this inside content editor webpart

```
<style>
#SPFieldText {
    font-weight:..., 
    size:...
}
</style>
```

Comment: This applies the format to all #SPFieldText fields...is there a way to target a single field?  I can't seem to use FieldName="something" or FieldInternalName="something" and I'm not seeing any ID numbers in the source.